Where am I going wrong here? is this a paradox? or are my assumptions bad?
Consider 4 random variables $A, B, C, D$ all initially taken from Uniform(0,1).
Let's call the pdfs of these random variables $a(x), b(x), c(x), d(x)$.
I want to find the posterior distributions of $A, B, C, D$ given some conditions (i.e. $A>B$, or $C$ is top 2, etc.)

Is it fair to assume that $a(x) + b(x) + c(x) + d(x)$ = $4$ ($\forall$ $x\in [0,1]$) for any set of conditions since it must be a linear combination of the $4!=24$ possible rankings?

In each of the 24 rankings the max has pdf $4x^3$, 2nd highest is $12x^2(1-x)$, 3rd is $12x(1-x)^2$, min is $4(1-x)^3$.

Given prior distributions $a(x)$ and $b(x)$, knowing $A>B$ results in a posterior distribution of $a'(x) = j\cdot a(x)\cdot B(x)$ and $b'(x) = k\cdot b(x)\cdot (1-A(x))$ for some constants $j, k$ where $A(x)$ is the integral of a(x), such that $A(0)=0$.

Consider a simplified version of 2. when $a(x)=b(x)$, this will allow us to avoid updating pdfs after the fact (this analogous to Elo rating system being forward pass instead of 1 huge computation)


Example Scenario: $A, B, C, D$ are being compared in a single elimination tournament. We find $A>D$, $B>C$, $A>B$, $C>D$

Initially $a(x) = b(x) = c(x) = d(x) = 1$.
After $A>D$, $a'(x) = 2x$, $d'(x) = 2(1-x)$
Similarly after $B > C$, $b'(x) = 2x$, $c'(x) = 2(1-x)$
After $A>B$, $a''(x) = 4 x^3$, $b''(x) = 4x(1-x^2)$
After $C>D$, $c''(x) = 4 (1-x)(1-(1-x)^2)$, $d''(x) = 4(1-x)^3$

This satisfies criteria 1. the whole time. Also, note this is slightly different than the true posterior since $b''(x)$ should $=c''(x)$ since they both beat $D$ and lost to $A$, but $E[B] = \frac8{15} > \frac7{15} = E[C]$. This "bug" can be considered a "feature" since it is dependent on the order of the comparisons (i.e. WL is better than LW in Swiss tournaments for example) and like I said earlier it is a forward pass system.
So here is my "paradox" scenario:

$D$ is last
$A$ is top 2
$B>C$
$B>A$

Approach 1: Intuitive
From the results we get

Initially $a(x) = b(x) = c(x) = d(x) = 1$.
After learning $D$ is last, $d'(x) = 4(1-x)^3$ and $a'(x)=b'(x)=c'(x) = \frac43(1-(1-x)^3)$
Knowing $A$ is top 2 means $a''(x) = 2x^3 + 6x^2(1-x)$ and $b''(x)=c''(x) = x^{3}+3x^{2}\left(1-x\right)+6x\left(1-x\right)^{2}\ $
With $B>C$, we have $b''(x) = a''(x) = 2x^3 + 6x^2(1-x)$, $c''(x)=12x(1-x)^2$
Then after $B>A$ we get $b'''(x) = 4x^3$, $a'''(x)=12x^2(1-x)$
In other words this is equivalent to knowing $B > A  > C > D$

This approach makes the most sense and is what I "want" to be true. But I don't the approach scales well computationally cause with $n$ numbers there are $n!$ scenarios to consider, while the integral approach should work well since it has a finite set of inputs.
Approach 2: Binary

Since $D$ is last and $A$ advances, this is analogous to the example scenario so $a'(x) = 2x$, $d'(x) = 2(1-x)$
Again after $B > C$, $b'(x) = 2x$, $c'(x) = 2(1-x)$
After $B>A$, $b''(x) = 4 x^3$, $a''(x) = 4x(1-x^2)$

This approach is pretty naive (doesn't account for $C>D$) and is trying to view this through a paradigm that only works for single-elimination tournaments with exactly a power of 2 contestants.
Approach 3: Modified Binary

In this approach, we set $a'(x)=b'(x)=c'(x)=\frac43x^\frac13$ and $d'(x)=4(1-x^\frac13)$
Then $a''(x)=b''(x) = 2x^\frac13 \cdot (x^\frac43)^\frac12 = 2x$ and $c''(x) = x^\frac13 \cdot (1-(x^\frac43)^\frac12) = 4(x^\frac13-x)$
Finally, $b'''(x) = 4 x^3$, $a'''(x) = 4x(1-x^2)$

Questions:

What are the biggest flaws in this method of converting comparisons into a probability distribution over $[0,1]$ and are they rectifiable?
Is there a valid way to extend this approach to say double elimination where the idea of greater than is somewhat fuzzy since a contestant isn't eliminated after their first loss?

To summarize, my goal with this method is to come up with an alternative for ranking performances in a tournament that is

precise (i.e. rational unlike Elo which uses floating point computation)
interpretable (a pdf over 0 to 1)
computationally simple (in contrast with matrix methods that require too much computation)

Ok, while writing this up I kind of answered my question, the two approaches have different assumptions about independence, I was hoping they'd be identical since they are for single-elimination tournaments with exactly a power of 2 contestants.
In simplest terms, here is the paradox:
Let A, B, C each be independently taken from [0,1]. We are given C is the smallest, so $a(x)=b(x)=\frac32(1-(1-x)^2)=3x-\frac32x^2$ and $c(x) = 3(1-x)^2$. Then $A(x) = B(x) = \frac32x-\frac12x^3$, so given $A>B$ $a'(x) = 2a(x)\cdot B(x) = 9x^{3}-7.5x^{4}+1.5x^{5}\neq3x^2$
another paradox I didn't like was how if $a(x) = 1$ and $b(x)=2x$, knowing whether $A>B$ affects the expected value of $A+B$. I was hoping for some sort of conservation of expected value.
Anyways, sorry for rambling I guess my main question now is whether it's possible to create an algorithm to calculate the intuitive method for a larger number of variables efficiently.
So as an example if we had 64 random variables, $a_1$ to $a_{64}$ and we knew $a_1$ is top 20, $a_2>a_3$, $a_4$ is last and say 100s of other criteria regarding the order of the 64 variables, would it be possible to come up with the pdfs of each variable efficiently or is this NP hard like SAT or something.
Here is a real world example to consider for more clarity on my question:
1981 NBA Season

12 teams in west, $w_1, w_2, \cdots, w_{12}$
11 teams in east, $e_1, e_2, \cdots, e_{11}$
6 teams make the playoffs from each conference, so $\min(w_1, w_2, \cdots, w_6)>\max(w_7, w_8, \cdots, w_{12})$ and $\min(e_1, e_2, \cdots, e_6)>\max(e_7, e_8, \cdots, e_{11})$
top 2 seeds get bye ($\text{rank}(w_1, w)\in\{1,2,3,4\}$, ($\text{rank}(w_2, w)\in\{1,2,3,4\}$, $\text{rank}(e_1, e)\in\{1,2,3,4\}$, ($\text{rank}(e_2, e)\in\{1,2,3,4\}$)

This example is kind of difficult to view through the methodology I put forward for a few reasons

The byes make it tricky since given $w_3>w_6$, the pdfs of $w_2$ and $w_3$ differ since $w_3$ could be ranked 5th (if $w_5>w_4>w_3$) while $w_2$ cannot since they had a 1st round bye
The finals is also asymmetric since the winner of west has pdf $w(x)=12x^{11}$ versus the winner of the east having $e(x)=11x^10$, so even though the NBA champion has a pdf of $24x^23$ regardless the loser's pdf depends on their conference which violates assumption 1
This suggests we may need to consider all $23!$ possibilities which could be computationally intractable
Also note we something like a Young tableau to know exactly how many possibilities there are

In our case it is $\frac{23!}{23\cdot12\cdot10\cdot9\cdot9\cdot7\cdot7\cdot9\cdot8\cdot7\cdot6\cdot6}$ which is ~130 billion possibilities.

It's hard to know what you are thinking. In your first line you define exactly what the marginal distributions are, yet a couple of paragraphs later you seem to have some doubt about them. There are also odd things such as defining $A(x)$ without using the term "cumulative distribution function" or anything similar.

If the purpose is "ranking performances in a tournament", how do you handle the case where A wins against B, B wins against C, and C wins against A? I note that Elo rankings assume performance is a random variable whose distribution can be identified by a single parameter (i.e., when we estimate a new mean, the pdf shifts uniformly left or right). You seem to be doing something completely different, but I can't tell what.
